# Bootstrap - Column position jumping if the window is resized?

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

EDIT: Updated the code and cleaned it up and reworked it almost completely

I'm currently experiencing a pretty strange problem with the bootstrap columns. I coded the site for a client and noticed just now, that on my dynamically created list of items, the last column is jumping around in its position from bottom-left to bottom-middle quite rapidly when you resize the window in chrome. Additionally, in firefox, the tile just stays in the bottom-middle although if you look at the code, this shouldnt be the case at all since its just normal col-md-4s after each other.

What is causing this issue?

EDIT: ok nevermind, its just a floating problem with the bootstrap divs...

If needed, the php code that creates the columns:

```
<?php
$pagelinks = array();
$currentWork = 0;

<div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="row">

<?php 

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'post'
    ));

if( $posts ): 

    foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post );

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 col-small-padding portfolioImage">           
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="box">          
                        <img src="<?php echo get_field('projekt-vorschaubild'); ?>">
                        <div class="caption fade-caption defaultFont">
                        <?  if(get_field("ausgezeichnetes_projekt") == true){
                                echo '<img src="';
                                echo bloginfo('template_directory');
                                echo '/images/icons/Icon_Awarded_Project.svg" class="awardedIcon"><h2>'.get_field('title').'</h2>';
                        }
                            else
                                echo '<h2>'.get_field('title').'</h2>'; ?>
                        <p> <? get_field('caption'); ?> </p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
            $currentWork++;

    endforeach;
    wp_reset_postdata();

endif; ?>

  </div> 

  </div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap uses a 12 column grid... Why do you have `col-md-15` there?

Comment: @TimLewis My thoughts exactly, this would explain going from 6 to 12(!?) or back to something (unknown behaviour?)

Comment: The col-md-15 is a custom class that basically allows me to get 5 columns into the bootstrap grid. But I see, I didn't even think that this could be the issue. I got rid of it now and updated the code to a col-4 layout but the problem still exists :/